# Problem with MergeList/var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages

Tags: 16.04, package-management, updates, dependencies

I am new to Ubuntu and is using 16.04.
Recently I got a notification at the top of the desktop saying:

> An error occured, please run package manager or apt-get to see whats wrong. The error message was error opening the cache:
>
> ```
> E:encountered a section with no Package: header,
> E: Problem with MergeList/var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages
> E:The Package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.)This usually means your installed packages have unmet dependencies.
> ```

I do not have Package Manager installed and I cannot open Ubuntu Software Center anymore. I have tried running `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get -f install` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Indian mirror `in.archive.ubuntu.com` gave you a malformed package list file; this seems to be a common occurence with this mirror (among others).

Just do nothing, eventually the mirror should return to a sane state and the error will disappear.